# Grails : Scaffolding with Search plugin

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I want to integrate search plugin(lucene) of grails with scaffolding feature

Basically when we show list of records via scaffolding we want to make it searchable by using search plugin.

Anyone knows how to do this ? What we understand is there is different controller for search and scaffolding hence it might not be possible.

Example code link will be helpful.

Comment: are you talking about the [searchable plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the fields plugin.  That may allow you some of what you are looking for.

http://grails.org/plugin/fields